# Incorrect datetime value in MySQL 8 - How to fix?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `projects` (`name`, `created_at`) VALUES ('test', '2015-01-21 04:09:46');
INSERT INTO `projects` (`name`, `created_at`) VALUES ('test', '2016-03-27 01:29:59');
```

The first query run good, the second given an error: Error in query (1292): Incorrect datetime value: '2016-03-27 01:29:59' for column 'created_at' at row 1

The sql_mode is:

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

The table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `projects`;
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

MySQL version: 8.0.19

Comment: Those bits of the table you decided to hide, MAY possible be relevant

Comment: Since your profile says you're from portugal, on `2016-03-27` the clocks were turned forward from `01:00:00` to `02:00:00` (daylight saving time), so `01:29:59` didn't exist at that date.

Comment: On my system, it actually creates a row with the time as 02:00:00 Does it do that on yours

Comment: @tkausl thanks. My system_time_zone: WEST and time_zone: SYSTEM. How I can fix it?

Comment: You can fix it by not entering an invalid time, or store UTC time instead of a time that observes summertime changes

Answer (score 0):

Please change created_at data type to `created_at datetime DEFAULT NULL`

Then try to insert the value.